# Plot series in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am new in Matlab and I am trying to plot this function in Matlab:

[image]
I am using the following code:

```
t = -2*pi:0.01:2*pi;
f = sum(cos(2*pi*i*t), i = 1 .. 10);
plot(t, f)
```

But I getting this message error:

```
f = sum(cos(2*pi*i*t), i = 1 .. 10);
                            |
Error: The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment.
```

Can anyone help me?

```
EDIT: I am using Matlab 2013a
```

Comment: @lakesh since `t` is 1x1257 and `1:10` is 1x10, `1:10*t` will not work. @marcelo `f = sum(cos(2*pi*i*t), i = 1 .. 10);` is not Matlab syntax. Read the documentation for `sum`: http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/sum.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 t = -2 * pi : 4 * pi / 500 : 2 * pi;
 f = sum(cos(2 * pi * (1 : 10)' * t), 1);
 plot(t, f);
```

- *doc sum*, of course ))